# $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^2\right)^2 \stackrel{?}{=} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^4 $ where $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^2\right)^2 \text{equal to} \sum\limits_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^4 $ where $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ ??

If not then how to expand: $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^2\right)^2$

Thanks

Comment: No it is not correct...

Comment: Actually this is true if and only if $a_i=-b_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: @Lost1 thanks!!

Comment: Weird question. I suspect OP didn't ask the *real question* he intended to ask.

Answer (score 5):

No. Take $a_i=2, b_i=0$. Then $16N^2\ne 16N$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Let $u_i=(a_i+b_i)^2$, and notice that $(\sum_{i}u_i)^2=\sum_{i,j}u_iu_j$ then you go from there.

Comment: If $(\sum_{i}u_i)^2=\sum_{i,j}u_iu_j$, that means $i$ may not be equal to $j$. In that case it will not be equal to $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^2\right)^2$.

Comment: what do you mean?  i and j are indices of the summation.  Double sum actually.

Answer (score 1):

See [Expansion of the square of the sum of $N$ numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187687/expansion-of-the-square-of-the-sum-of-n-numbers).

\begin{equation*}
[\sum_{i=1}^N(a_i+b_i)^2]^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N (a_i+b_i)^4 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} (a_i+b_i)^2(a_j+b_j)^2
\end{equation*}