# Rearrangement of summation definition of variance

Tags: statistics, variance, linear-regression

I'm following a proof of simple linear regression as detailed in Chapter 24 of *The Probability Lifesaver* by Stephen J Miller. There's one step involving the variance that the author explains as "simple algebra" that I can't fill in the blanks for:

$$ = N^2 (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x^2_n - \bar{x}^2) $$
$$ = N^2 (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n - \bar{x})^2) $$

It seems clear that this is an application of the theorem:

$$Var(X) = E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - E[X]$$

However I'm lost as to how to demonstrate that using purely algebra and the properties of summations as the author suggests. I tried looking at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909963/how-to-expand-summations-in-this-variance-proof) for clarity but didn't find much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-\bar{x})^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N (x_n^2 -2 \bar{x} x_n + \bar{x}^2 \\
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2 - \frac{2}{N}\bar{x} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N x_n \right) + \bar{x}^2 , $$
since $ \frac{1}{N} \sum_n a = a $ for $a$ a constant. The key thing now is to recognise the definition of $\bar{x}$, namely
$$ \bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N x_n . $$
But that means that the middle term is actually $-2\bar{x}^2$. Hence the sum becomes
$$ \left( \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x_n^2 \right) - \bar{x}^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n^2 - \bar{x}^2 ) $$
as required.