# Relating $\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2 e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}$ to $(\;\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}\;)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, fourier-transform, sums-of-squares

Consider the following expression
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2 e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}\tag{1}
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary number. How may I relate it to the following expression
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}\right)^2
$$
**My attempt:** [I know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187687/expansion-of-the-square-of-the-sum-of-n-numbers)
$$
\left( \sum_{k=1}^N x_k \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} x_k x_j 
$$
With $x_k\equiv a_k e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}$ I get
$$
\left( \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k} \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k^2 e^{\frac{4\pi i}{N}k} + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} a_ka_j e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}(k+j)} 
$$
where the first term of the right-hand side is close to my initial term $(1)$. Any ideas on how to proceed from here? I wonder if there are some special properties about $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}$ and Fourier transforms that I could use.